# Replace an element in a 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I continue to make my sudoku solver but I have a problem with my 2d list.

My sudoku file txt looks like this :

```
..3 ... ...
etc...
```

So here, right now, with this function :

```
def grid_index(grid, value):
    for i, row in enumerate(grid):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row):
             if cell == value:
                return i, j
    return -1, -1
print("Coords:",grid_index(sudoku, "."))
```

I found the first empty element who need to be change. The output is (0,0).

Now, my point is to replace the element "." by 1 (for example) with the coordinates.

My function to change is :

```
def solve_next_unsolved(sudoku):
    coords = grid_index(sudoku, ".") # so here i get coordinate to the point element
    number_to_input = 1
```

Should I get the element with coordinates? How can I change the element found by my `grid_index()` function with `1`?

Comment: `sudoku[coords[0]][coords[1]] = number_to_input` ?

Comment: wtf yeah... it's... -_- Please delete this topic ! XD

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply change the value of the list item using its indexes ?

```
grid[i][j] = 1 # Or whatever value you want
```

Comment: This would, of course, be the obvious thing to try. However, I have a list of lists of strings `l = 5*[ 5*[ "0" ] ]` which I am trying to change the i-j-th element of, and doing `l[i][j] = "1"` changes the j-th element of _every_ sublist to `"1"`, and not just of the i-th sublist. Any ideas why?

Comment: Never mind, I found answers [here](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Change-single-element-in-2D-list-changes-every-1D-element) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of pandas' dataframes? it should work quite well for your problem i think. This creates your grid (with your_initial_grid being a list of your the rows of your grid).

```
import pandas as pd
grid = pd.dataframe(your_initial_grid)
```

Then you can easily change of case's value by:

```
grid.iloc[i,j] = whatever_number_you_want
```

Comment: I don't know what is it. I'm going to look that. thanks for information

Comment: You're welcome! if you need any information, don't hesitate!